# EF4.1 inserting current date/time

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, entity-framework-4.1

Often times in my SQL Server database, I'll declare a CreatedDate field.  It is set to non-nullable and the default value is GetDate().  This works just fine to force a created date.

I can't fgure out how to do this using EF4.1.  I see in the designer there is a place for Default Value, but I'm not sure if I can enter a function for this.

I also tried to set it as nullable in the EF designer, and just let SQL Server do the populating, but it didn't like this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `GetDate` when using EF unless you mark `CreatedDate` column as `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`. In such case you will not be able to set this value in your application and database will be responsible for that.

If you don't set `StoreGeneratedPattern` you must set the data in your application (designer doesn't allow setting default value to current date). So you must either manually populate `CreatedDate` or use some trick like your own partial part of the entity class with default constructor setting this property:

```
public partial class YourEntity
{
    public YourEntity()
    {
        CretedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```